# PDFBOX2.X - Read wrong Data from acroForm

Tags: pdfbox

We are facing issue while reading data from acroform.

We are using PDFBOX2.x version to create PDF file. Our goal was to make pdf executable means we can download pdf file which contains acroform. We can collect data and later we can upload it to sync with database.

We are facing issue in which PDFBox debugger or we can say in upload file. Our textbox value is getting changed automatically.

PLease see more details in below image.

We have used PDF Debugger tool to check PDF content. You can see that totalBuyoffCount value is 0. But it should be 3.

[image]

I have used iTextDebugger to check same field
[image]

It is totally random behavior and we have noticed following things

Sometimes 0 or 1 value became N or Y
Very few fields are affected but it causes NumberFormat exception if it’s converted into String value.
It’s makes our whole file corrupted.

If it cannot be fixed then could you tell me in which area we need to see so that we can understand and debug why it’s value changed or from where value is retrieved  so in case if we find then  we can change or override this behavior

Comment: Please describe the detailed issue here and not in an external location.

Comment: I have updated description

Comment: This is not enough. Please post the code that shows what you're doing. "Sometimes 0 or 1 value became N or Y" - how did this happen? Did the screenshots of RUPS and PDFDebugger come with the same file? Please tell what PDFBox version you are using (there is no version "2.X") and please share the file.

Comment: Yes I was using same file in RUPS and PDFDebugger.
File:-
https://drive.google.com/open?id=13NkvML3RHbU-Ms2x_eHAz01NdzadmZC1

I am using PDFBOX2.0.0 I was facing same issue with 2.0.7 also

Comment: I don't have RUPS but I looked at the PDF file with NOTEPAD++. Search for "1499 0 obj". A few lines below, you'll see "/V (0)". And not 3.

Comment: Yes. but question is we have value 3 and we expect 3 not 0. RUPS gives the correct value. but not the PDFBOX.

Comment: Could you check again with RUPS by downloading your own file from the link in the comment and using that one?

Comment: I am getting 3 in value. I again download iText RUPS from  https://github.com/itext/rups/releases 
checking using itext-rups-5.5.9-jar-with-dependencies.jar

I am planning to use itext-2.1.7 to retrieve data from PDF.

Comment: @Tilman *I looked at the PDF file with NOTEPAD++. Search for "1499 0 obj". A few lines below, you'll see "/V (0)". And not 3.* - That does not mean a lot because the PDF is encrypted. Effectively the question is whether the string `0` decrypts to "0" or to "3". (Or whether `0` simply is not a valid encrypted string and the decryption result is arbitrary...)

Comment: @JanakPatel While I try to fix the bug (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4453 ), as a workaround you could use AES256 encryption. This produces more different strings in encryption. Note that key length and AES are set separately (with `StandardProtectionPolicy.setPreferAES`). Or alternatively not using encryption.

Comment: @JanakPatel snapshot build is here: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.14-SNAPSHOT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the PDF object in question (1499, gen 0) one finds

```
1499 0 obj
<<
/FT /Tx
/Q 0
/V (0)
/Ff 1
/Rect [0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0]
/Type /Annot
/Subtype /Widget
/T <77A2A671303FC282631C0C903EA8F40F>
/DA <2C85B77C2A5D81D53C5A3EB571EDBA1C>
/F 6
>>
endobj
```

So one might be tempted to say *you see "/V (0)". And not 3.*

While this is correct, it unfortunately does not mean a lot because the file is encrypted!

Thus, the question burns down to whether the string `0` in object 1499, generation 0, decrypts to "0" or to "3".

I have not implemented a PDF decrypter myself, so I cannot claim to check this with my own code.

The second best I can do is check against what Adobe decrypts that value to. My good old Adobe Acrobat 9.5 Preflight shows:

[image: Preflight screen shot]

Apparently Adobe just like iText decrypts this `0` to "3". Additional checks with an online PDF decrypter or two support this decryption result.

Thus, it appears that PDFBox does not properly decrypt this `0` string.

Considering the OP's further observation *"Sometimes 0 or 1 value became N or Y Very few fields are affected"* it looks like PDFBox sometimes does not correctly decrypt single character strings.

An alternative option would be that there is some issue in the encryption parameters of the file in question. I don't really believe this but I cannot preclude it.

#### The bug

As Tilman already hinted at in his comments to [PDFBOX-4453](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4453), the bug is due to the way PDFBox and in particular the `SecurityHandler` keeps track of which objects already have been decrypted and which still have to be: The already decrypted objects are stored in the `HashSet SecurityHandler.objects`; when asked to decrypt an object, `SecurityHandler.decrypt` first checks whether that object is in that set, and only if it is not, it is actually decrypted and added to the set.

Thus, if a still encrypted object `equals` an already decrypted one, a call to decrypt this encrypted object won't do anything at all.

In the file at hand there has been a string before that has been decrypted to "0". Thus, when the encrypted value of `totalBuyoffCount`, `0`, is sent to the `SecurityHandler` for decryption, the value falsely is assumed to already be decrypted, so it remains as it is.

For longer strings this usually is no issue as their encrypted versions usually are completely garbled, so they won't be found among the already decrypted objects. Short strings, in particular single-character ones, on the other hand might have encrypted versions that make sense, so collisions may happen.

Options to fix this are discussed in the referenced Apache Jira issue. One option would be to replace the mentioned set by a flag of the individual objects in question but other options also are possible.

Comment: Thank you guys. When we expect that 2.0.14 version will be released?

Comment: Don't know... new releases are usually every 3-6 months, and the last one was in december. Until then, use the workaround in my other comment. RC4 40 bits is not really good encryption.